# Dynamic value for cookie secure flag at web.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to set the "cookie-config secure" flag on my web.xml dynamically based on my environment.

I know I can do this with maven build, but I want to make it a single war file that can be used in multi-environment instead of different war file.

Is there any way to set it based on my environment variable or parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized it easily can be achieved using Java system properties. 
Just need to add -Dsome.value on JAVA_OPTS
And use ${some.value} at the web.xml file.